# unable to use "d2xx" library for FTDI chips in python

Tags: python, ftdi

[Downloaded the d2xx library from this site](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/h33CzWSEdo7Wju9EEk3wUg?feat=directlink)
Works fine on Windows7 with python2.6

[List of extracted files.](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/h33CzWSEdo7Wju9EEk3wUg?feat=directlink)
In  Ubuntu 10.10(Maverick Meerkat) I cannot proceed further.
how to install the files so that I can import d2xx library

$make

Makefile:1: Makefile.conf: No such file or directory

make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile.conf'.  Stop.

$sudo python setup.py install

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "setup.py", line 4, in 

    from conf import *

ImportError: No module named conf

---

I am using python 2.6. Cant proceed further with the installation. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [appears](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/OtherPlatforms.htm) that the [PyUSB](http://bleyer.org/pyusb) interface for FTDI drivers only provides support for Windows at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The libftdi drivers which use libusb have python bindings which will work in linux.
The function api's are slightly different but will accomplish the same thing.  libftdi and libusb can also be used on windows if that's important.

http://idle-logic.com/2010/12/13/libftdi-v0-18-with-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/

This guy's blog describes a project which he uses python wrapped libftdi libraries which he uses to program an FPGA over USB.

Answer (score 0):

While PyUSB is only officially supported on Windows, it's possible to build it for linux as well. There are three routines that didn't have a linux equivalent (well, maybe they do but I didn't look to hard), but you may not need them.  See my [post on using PyUSB on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615308/using-ftdi-d2xx-drivers-with-python-from-raspberry-pi-on-raspbian-soft-float).